# Unable to take same type in std::variant

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm using c++17, and would like to write the code something like this,

```
#include <variant>
typedef int NewInt;
int main() {
    std::variant<NewInt, int> n = 1;
}
```

But it emits compile error,

```
po.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
po.cpp:5:35: error: conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘std::variant<int, int>’ requested
     std::variant<NewInt, int> n = 1;
                               ^
```

How could I define the type like `std::variant<NewInt, int>` or is it impossible?

Comment: You have `std::variant<int, int>`. The error would be due to that. Can you check with something else instead of `NewInt`? For example, `std::variant<std::string, int> n = 1;

Comment: Your approach doesn't work. You don't need C++17 for that, even in C++98 you would run into trouble if you thought, say, that `void f(int)` and `void f(NewInt)` were distinct overloads. As of C++17, though, you could perhaps define `enum class NewInt : int {};` as a "strong int type".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A type alias is just another name for an existing type, not a new type. So you have a variant of two ints. And while it's allowed, you must address the ambiguity explicitly. `std::variant` has a suitable constructor:

```
std::variant<NewInt, int> n{ std::in_place_index<0>, 1 };
```

The above will construct the first integer member (your `NewInt`). If you want to construct the second, it's the obvious:

```
std::variant<NewInt, int> n{ std::in_place_index<1>, 1 };
```

Comment: Till date, I still haven't seen much practical use of having the same types in `std::variant`... Or is it just to provide opportunity for some sort of consistency? You know any practical use case?

Comment: @WhiZTiM - Not the same type no. But the same type with different `cv-qualifers`, yes. I think allowing the same exact type is just a derivative of that, not an exact goal.

Comment: @StoryTeller No, it was a goal; sum types need to be able to add the same type more than once for certain kinds of generic code and manipulations to work.

Comment: @WhiZTiM - Well, there you have it. Should have known there's something I didn't encounter yet :)

Comment: @WhiZTiM I encountered a case where I wanted the same types in a variant (actually `boost::variant`). I had a variant containing some unsigned types and `std::size_t`. `std::variant<std::uint32_t, std::uint64_t, std::size_t>` is going to fail (almost certainly), as `std::size_t` will be the same as one of the other unsigned ints. And `std::variant<std::uint32_t, std::size_t>` may or may not compile, depending on the size of `std::size_t` (yes, `size_t` is probably not `uint64_t`, but there's no guarantee on exactly what size it is)

Comment: Yeah, true that's a very valid reason. One other thought: libc++ and libstdc++ use a lot of type punning in across their codebase. Such as `union Tag{ T value; const T const_value };`, its easy to pun between the two members... However, I don't see how `std::variant` will allow you *view* `value` through `const_value` since, its very strict on tagging the active members. Or can `std::variant` do so?

Comment: @WhiZTiM No, `std::variant` is not for type punning at all. It can't be used for that.