# Accessing std::variant using std::get<index>

Tags: c++, std, c++17, variant

How can I access members of variant using `v.index()` then `std::get<index>(v)`?

Useful when the variant has multiple entries of the same type.

The following does not work. This code doesn't compile on either GCC or clang

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

typedef std::variant<int, int, std::string> foo;

std::string bar(const foo f) {

    const std::size_t fi = f.index();
    auto ff = std::get<fi>(f);

    std::ostringstream ss;      
    ss << "Index:" << fi << "   Value: " << ff;
    return ss.str();
}


int main()
{
    foo f( 0 );

    std::cout << bar(f);
}
```

There are many versions of std::get of course, so the error messages are lengthy.

gcc complains (for every version of get<>)

```
prog.cc:10:29: error: the value of 'fi' is not usable in a constant expression
     auto ff = std::get<fi>(f);
                             ^
prog.cc:9:23: note: 'fi' was not initialized with a constant expression
     const std::size_t fi = f.index();
                       ^~
prog.cc:10:29: note: in template argument for type 'long unsigned int'
     auto ff = std::get<fi>(f);
```

Clang complains (for every version of get<>)
(re _Tp or _Ip as the case may be)

```
candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter '_Tp'
```

[Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VCCXvRxs7HGzCmDA)

UPDATED to ask how to solve rather than what does the error message mean.

Comment: The template parameter to `std::get` has to be either the index or the type of the element in the variant.  So your choices are `<0>`, `<1>`, `<int>`, or `<std::string>`.

Comment: Actually the standard specifies std::size_t

Comment: @md5i non-type template arguments can be a different type to the parameter, so long as there is a unique implicit conversion available (roughly speaking)

Comment: Is your question actually about how to output the currently active member of a variant? (not necessarily using `get`)

Comment: @M.M Yes I guess so. Specifically when there are multiple uses of a type in the variant.

Comment: @M.M Not here.  See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get).  Note the _ill formed_ statements.

Comment: @md5i `0` is a valid index in the variant; point 1 (which is what this case is) is not saying anything about the type of the index argument. You can use `0`, `0L`, `(size_t)0` etc.  Point 2 is talking about `get<long>(f)` which would be ill-formed.

Comment: @M.M  Yes.  The template parameter must be either a constexpr converting to `std::size_t` or a unique type in the variant.

Comment: What is a point to put same type multiple times to variant?

Comment: @Slava imagine `typedef int number_of_apples` and `typedef int number_of_bananas`

Comment: So maybe I should std::visit using the index?

Comment: @Slava [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47858965/unable-to-take-same-type-in-stdvariant) for a use-case

Comment: @KarlM and how do you assign number of bananas to an instance of this variant?

Comment: @M.M looks like misuse-case for me - requires to always create instance with special ctor

Comment: @Slava A few ways. e.g `v.emplace<0>(7)` or `v.emplace<1>(19)`

Comment: @KarlM good, now how to implement visitor?

Comment: @Slava, yes that is my question

Comment: @KarlM no it is not, you ask how to call `std::get<>()` I am asking how to implement visitor

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`std::get<>` is applicable when requesting a variant index that is known at **compile time**.

If you need to act on a variant value whose type isn't known until **runtime**, the idiomatic approach is to use a visitor with `std::visit`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <string>

struct output_visitor
{
    template< typename T >
    void operator() ( const T& value ) const
    {
        std::cout << value;
    }   
};

int main()
{
    std::variant<int, std::string> f( 0 );

    std::visit( output_visitor{}, f );
}
```

This can often be implemented with C++14 "generic lambdas"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::variant<int, std::string> f( 0 );

    std::visit( [](auto v){std::cout << v;} , f );
}
```

Comment: note: OP specifically asks about the case of a repeated type in the variant type list; in which case you couldn't use the initializer `( 0 )`

Comment: There are further examples on [cppreference visit page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit)

Comment: Thanks! Also, I'd like to know the value of index() - not to use in a get<> though. I guess you could pass f in through output_visitor constructor.

Comment: This is the answer? And how are you going to differentiate first `int` from the second in this visitor?

Comment: @Slava If that distinction was important (It's not if the goal is just to output the value) then you could also read `f.index()` at any stage

Comment: @M.M I am trying to imagine such code, seems to be ugly. I think it is wrong approach to use the same type multiple times

Comment: @Slava: It usually happens through type aliases. You could have a `variant<int, std::int32_t>`; it is very possible that the latter is an alias for the former on some implementations. How much you care which index it is depends on the circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

[gcc 8.1's error output](https://godbolt.org/g/nX17jH) also includes the explanation:

> ```
> <source>:10:29: error: the value of 'fi' is not usable in a constant expression
>     auto ff = std::get<fi>(f);
>                         ^
> <source>:9:23: note: 'fi' was not initialized with a constant expression
>    const std::size_t fi = f.index();
> ```

Integer template arguments have to be constant expressions.  `f` is not a constant expression, therefore a call to its non-static member function is not a constant expression, therefore `fi` is not.

You can get a better error message with:

```
constexpr std::size_t fi = f.index();
```

The code `get<fi>(f)` could only work if `f` were also declared to be `constexpr` ;  but that is only possible if all the types in the variant have trivial destructors,  which `std::string` does not.

Comment: Thanks! I updated with a better question. How do I solve the problem rather than what does the error message mean. Also a more complicated example.

Comment: @KarlM you just can't do `get<fi>`  ,  types must be known at compile-time

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Of course the types are known at compile-time.

Comment: @KarlM It is not known when compiling `std::string bar(const foo f)` whether the active member of `f` is `int` or `string`; so you cannot have an expression referring to the active member of `f` because that expression's type would not be known at compile-time

Comment: ok , hence constexpr. I understand. So what do I do about it?

Comment: @KarlM See Drew Dormann's answer for that (I won't rehash it!).