# c++: getting the "held" index of a variant without using std::get

Tags: c++, variant

```
std::variant<int, float> var{42};
unsigned int index=std::get<0>(var);
```

This clearly works, but say `n` in `std::get<n>(var)` is determined at run-time, is there an alternative to access the held variant, i.e. a template-free solution?

Comment: Do you need to access by index, or can it be type? Or maybe I'll put it the other way: do you want to map the index into type?

Comment: Which would be the return type of `get(n, var)`?

Comment: At runtime, you can use the [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit)

Comment: @alagner Not really. My objective is to get the object held by the variant.

Comment: Regular way to use  `std::variant` is with `st::visit`.

Comment: @Simon check `std::visit` or `std::get_if`. It really depends on your exact use case.

Comment: Of course, I could just an if-statement to get the correct type of the invariant using std::get. But I thought there is maybe a more efficient way.

Comment: Might be useful to use the return value of `std::visit`: `unsigned int index = std::visit([](auto& value) -> unsigned int { return value; }, var);` or `auto index = std::visit<unsigned int>(std::identity{}, var);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a `std::variant` value when the index is determined at runtime, you can use `std::visit` with a visitor or a generic lambda. This approach is more idiomatic than using `std::get` with a runtime index. Here's two examples using a visitor and a generic lambda, respectively:

Visitor:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <string>

struct output_visitor
{
    template< typename T >
    void operator() (const T& value) const
    {
        std::cout << value;
    }   
};

int main()
{
    std::variant<int, std::string> f(0);
    std::visit(output_visitor{}, f);
}
```

Generic Lambda:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::variant<int, std::string> f(0);
    std::visit([](auto v){std::cout << v;}, f );
}
```

Both examples above print the value held by the variant. If you need to access the index at runtime, you can use the `.index()` method on the variant object [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51624070/accessing-stdvariant-using-stdgetindex).

However, note that `std::get` with a runtime index is not possible because the index in `std::get<n>` must be a constant expression [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51624070/accessing-stdvariant-using-stdgetindex).

another example on how you can pass a second argument to the lambda function when using `std::visit`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::variant<int, std::string> f(0);
    int second_arg = 10;
    std::variant<int> second_arg_variant(second_arg);

    std::visit([](auto&& v, auto&& v2) { std::cout << v << " " << v2; }, f, second_arg_variant);
}
```

The lambda function accepts two forwarding references auto&&, allowing it to work with lvalues and rvalues. The lambda prints the value held by the first variant f and the second variant second_arg_variant with a space in between.

Comment: Is there a way to pass a second argument to the lambda function?

Comment: @Simon Yes, you can do this by modifying the lambda function inside std::visit to accept two arguments and pass the second argument after the variant.

Comment: Can you show that in your answer please? Based on what I understood, it is not possible to write something like `std::visit([](auto v, auto v2){std::cout << v;}, f, v2 );`

Comment: @simon: Use capture in the lambda for non-variant parameters.

Comment: @Jarod42 Also  `std::visit([](auto v, auto & v2){std::cout << v;}, f, v2 );` does not work for me

Comment: @Kozydot should `+` be `<<` instead? It doesn't make sense to add an `int` and a `std::string`. Also, consider using `auto&&` in the lambda argument

Comment: @RemyLebeau you're correct sorry for the confusion